# magento manual theme install

Tags: magento, themes

Hi I am a newbie to magento I want to install a magento theme that I found on the internet manually 
in the theme there are 3 folders that I see after unzipping it

1.extension
2.source
3.Template full
4.Template only

now the extension folder has sub folders like
catalogue sorter,featured product,product navigator,theme switcher.
now each of these folders has sub folders having 
app
js
skin folders

source folder has fonts and psd files in it

template full and template only has
app
js
skin
themedata sub folders

with all these similar folders I can't just understand how to install this theme,all the tutorials in the net says that copy the app,js,skin files into the magento root folder and clean the cache you will,see the installer .But my problem is that in this theme there are multiple app,js,skin,themedata folders that is really confusing me.
Any kind of help is appreciated 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How to apply a new theme :
Possibly there are three ways to aply a new theme :
One:simply go to the theme folder and copy the required folder reading the theme apply instructions
And paste the copied foder in the C:\wamp\www\apparel location and find the theme name 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you download or placed your theme to the folder.

Navigate to **System** -> **Design** and click on **Add Design Change**.
Choose the theme you want, click on **save** and you’re done.

Refer this http://tutorialmagento.com/magento-theme-development-tutorial-for-designer-part-1

Hope it will help you.